# Redis delete element in multiple sets

Tags: redis

I have an element XYZ in multiples sets and i nee to delete is from all the sets.

I could do:

```
SADD SET1 1 2 3
SADD SET2 3 4 5
```

And:

```
SREM SET1 3
SREM SET2 3
```

But I don't know the name of the sets in advance, is there a simple way to do something like

```
FOREACH SET* do SREM 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep another set of Sets that maps elements to the Sets that they're in. In your example, that would mean:

```
SADD member:1 SET1
SADD member:2 SET1
SADD member:3 SET1 SET2
SADD member:4 SET2
SADD member:5 SET2
```

Once everything is set, all you need to do is get the members in the member:3 Set and continue with the "FOREACH".